# Convolution of sine and cosine.

Tags: calculus, convolution, gre-exam

So I came across this question while studying for the GRE Subject Exam, and I am not really sure how I am supposed to handle it. Let
$$ f(x) = \int _0 ^{\pi} \sin t \cos (x+t) dt $$
I am to find where $f$ gets its minimum and maximum values when $x \in [0,2\pi]$.

Since it is a GRE-question, I believe that the answer should not be that difficult. Could someone please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easiest way: calculate integral
$$\int _0 ^{\pi} \sin t \cos (x+t) dt=\frac{1}{2}\int _0 ^{\pi} (\sin (2t+x) -\sin (x) )dt=\\ \frac{1}{2}(-\frac{1}{2}\cos (2t+x)-t\sin (x))|^{\pi}_{0}=-\frac{\pi}{2}\sin (x)$$

Comment: Something does not look right here. Look at the expansion again.

Comment: I knew it had to be something easy!! Thanks for the idea! Although I think you made a mistake in your calculations. You are using the identity $2 \sin A \cos B = \sin (A+B) + \sin (A-B)$ right?

Comment: it's easy indeed but I'm using this identity in integral $2\sin(A)\cos(B)=\sin(A+B)+\sin(A-B)$

Answer (score 4):

Using the formula $\cos(x + t) = \cos x \cos t - \sin x \sin t$, you can split the integral and just calculate it.

\begin{align*}\int_0^\pi \sin t\cos(x + t)\ dt &= \int_0^\pi \sin t(\cos x \cos t - \sin x \sin t)\ dt\\
&=\cos x \underbrace{\int_0^\pi \sin t \cos t\ dt}_{=\,0} - \sin x\underbrace{\int_0^\pi \sin^2 t\ dt}_{=\, \pi/2} \\
&=-\frac{\pi}{2}\sin(x),
\end{align*}

which is maximized at $x = 3\pi/2$.

I'm sure there's a better perspective or way to do things, but this isn't *that* bad.

Comment: While your answer seems right, you didn't explain how you calculated the integral of $sin^2t$.  This is a somewhat complicated integral which I don't  think you are expected to know for the GRE.

Comment: Actually, my memory is that $\int\sin^2t\;dt$ is exactly the sort of integral that would appear on the GRE.

Comment: @browngreen $\sin^2(t) = \frac{1 - \cos(2t)}{2}$ (if I remember that one, anyone can -- I'm *terrible* at remembering things!), so you wind up integrating the cosine portion over a full period.

Comment: @carmichael561 Actually trig. identities are neccessary for the GRE, so it is something that GRE candidates should be able to calculate. There is a simpler way though, but this one will do just fine as well! Thank you!

Comment: @pjs36 I stand corrected then.

Answer (score 3):

By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have
$$\begin{aligned}
\left|\int_0^{\pi}\sin(t)\cos(x+t)dt\right| &\leq \left(\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^2(t) dt\right)^{1/2} \left(\int_0^{\pi}\cos^2(x+t)dt\right)^{1/2} \\
&= \frac{\pi}{2} \\
\end{aligned}$$
The right hand side is independent of $x$ because both integrands have period $\pi$.

Equality is achieved if and only if $\sin(t)$ and $\cos(x+t)$ are scalar multiples of each other. But this happens if and only if $x = \pi/2$ and $x=3\pi/2$. Specifically,
$$\cos(t+3\pi/2) = \cos(t-\pi/2) = \sin(t) \quad\text{and}\quad\cos(t+\pi/2) = -\sin(t)$$
so the minimum is achieved at $x=\pi/2$, and the maximum is achieved at $x = 3\pi/2$.

Comment: That's out of the box thinking! wow!

Comment: @christina_g: It's the lazy man's solution, for those who don't feel like calculating integrals :-)

Comment: Oh I can relate to that!! Thanks for the answer and the idea!!! :)